# How do I debug a command-line Dart app that uses async? (breakpoints not working)

Tags: dart, dart-async

The debugger in IntelliJ or the Dart Editor won't stop at the breakpoint for this code:

```dart
main() async {
    var x = 1;
    bool stop = true; // breakpoint here
}
```

... but does for this code:

```dart
main() {
    var x = 1;
    bool stop = true; // breakpoint here
}
```

Dart SDK 1.8.3 and latest stable releases on both IDEs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a known issue that is fixed in the *dev* channel and will be released in the *1.9* *stable* channel. See [Breakpoint set inside of async function does not trigger](http://dartbug.com/21590).

Comment: @aa -- The fix (3 days ago) is not in 1.9.0.dev_01_00 (DEV) (Dec. 10?) and I'm not finding a timetable/roadmap for Dart SDK releases. Can you point me to one?

Comment: oops. I thought it had been shipped. Sorry :)

Comment: I've been using the async_await transformer to convert async await code into standard code using only futures. Then you can debug as per usual. https://github.com/dart-lang/async_await

Comment: The [1.9.0-dev.3.0 64-bit Dart Editor Mac download](https://www.dartlang.org/tools/download-archive/) just worked for me in IntelliJ 14 and the Dart Editor on a simple Dart command-line script.